# Insert a variable into a JSON payload

Tags: json, python-3.x

I need to insert a variable (alerts) into a JSON template in order to POST it into a url:
I'm using `'{}'.format(alerts)` for insertion.
Variable:

```
alerts = [{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}]
```

This is the payload as it should be:

```
payload = {
    "Alerts":
        [{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}]
    ,
    "data2": {
        "account": ['123123123']
    }
}
```

But what I get is :

```
payload = {
    "Alerts":
        "[{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}]",
    "data2": {
        "account": ['123123123']
    }
}
```

Which has an extra `""` in the inserted data,
**"** [{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}] **"**

My question is - how do I get rid of the extra "" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try this:

```
import json

alerts = [{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}]

payload = {
    "data2": {
        "account": ['123123123']
    }
}

payload["alerts"] = alerts
print(json.dumps(payload, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Or do just this:

```
alerts = [{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}]

payload = {
    "alerts": alerts,
    "data2": {
        "account": ['123123123']
    }
}
print(json.dumps(payload, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Or use `.update()` on `payload`.

```
alerts = [{'alertno': '10', 'alertEmail': 'a@a.com'}]

payload = {
    "data2": {
        "account": ['123123123']
    }
}

payload.update({"alerts": alerts})
print(json.dumps(payload, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Output for all three ways is:

```
{
  "alerts": [
    {
      "alertEmail": "a@a.com",
      "alertno": "10"
    }
  ],
  "data2": {
    "account": [
      "123123123"
    ]
  }
}
```